# What the meaning of the ~once~ variable in the following code snippet?

Tags: go, control-flow

The question is about the usage `once` variable in the following snippet extracted from the [`pipe.go` of the standard go library](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/af37332d160e096fe5bedc551f318c7b76d4e57a/src/io/pipe.go#L86)

```
for once := true; once || len(b) > 0; once = false {
    select {
    case p.wrCh <- b:
        nw := <-p.rdCh
        b = b[nw:]
        n += nw
    case <-p.done:
        return n, p.writeCloseError()
    }
}
```

My understanding is that, the loop won't terminate as long as `len(b) > 0` and the loop would be executed at least once.

So why not just write

```
for len(b) > 0 { ... }
```

Comment: Because if `len(b) == 0` the loop wouldn't execute at all.

Comment: It makes sure that the loop body executes at least *once*, thus the name :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `once` is being used to make a `do ... while(condition);` loop, which Go does not have.